# How do you squash old commits together?

Tags: github, commit, squash

I am currently working in GitHub and I am struggling to squash commits together that I made a few days ago. Please bear in mind I'm 15 and don't have the largest range of knowledge in this area. I would really appreciate the help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to squash together your three most recent commits. Start with the command:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

How this breaks down:

- **git rebase** - You want to edit the current branch's commit history
- **-i** - You want to do this interactively via your favourite command-line text editor
- **HEAD~3** - You want to start at your most recent commit (HEAD) and incorporate the three commits stemming back from HEAD.

You'll be presented with a text file like so:

```
pick 543600b3e Some code added
pick e0b77fac3 Some other stuff
pick a97899876 My most recent commit
```

Your most recent commit will be at the bottom. To squash these commits down, replace the word `pick` with either of these two words:

- **squash** or **s** - Squash the commit, keeping the contents of the commit message
- **fixup** or **f** - Squash the commit, but **get rid** of the commit message

You'll normally want to keep the top line as `pick`. After you've made your changes, save and exit (usually <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> then <kbd>y</kbd> if you're using Nano) and your commits will be squashed down.